# Do we need a tikz 3.0 tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The recent update to `tikz` has motivated a few recent questions. Would it be helpful/appropriate to have a `tikz-pgf-3.0` tag?

Suitable questions that might receive this tag are, for example:

- [Does pgf 3.0.0 on ctan not have the arrows.meta tikz library?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166024/does-pgf-3-0-0-on-ctan-not-have-the-arrows-meta-tikz-library)
- [Problem with a path between pgf 2.1 and pgf 3.0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165090/problem-with-a-path-between-pgf-2-1-and-pgf-3-0)
- [Add more anchors to standard TikZ nodes with TikZ 3.0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164409/add-more-anchors-to-standard-tikz-nodes-with-tikz-3-0)

Comment: I'm always for adding (more) specific tags since it always be reverted (as synonyms). Moreover, it'll benefit in terms of searching (for those that actually use searches by tags).

Comment: As the bugs are solved and people update their distros, I guess this tag will be obsolete quickly. It happened with 2.00 and 2.10 if I remember correctly.

Comment: People don't use the appropriate tag in general.

Comment: @percusse looks like your comment received more upvotes than Werner's; would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: sorry forgot about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the bugs are solved and people update their distros, I guess this tag will be obsolete quickly. It happened with 2.00 and 2.10 if I remember correctly.